# How can I create a reference to a dynamic database name in a database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project, slowcheetah

I have multiple SQL Server database projects and I want to add a database reference from project A to project B.  However, the names of the databases that project A and B deploy to are different depending on the environment that I want to deploy to.  I'm already using SlowCheetah for app.config transformations across different build configurations.  Is there anything similar I can do with the database projects to transform the database name of the database reference based on the build configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add a database reference (using a dacpac), but add it with the option for the name to be a variable. Then reference that throughout your project with the SQLCMD variable syntax - $(DBName).

It will take a bit of work, but you can build that into your Publish Profiles or pass the variable in to the SQLPackage command. The Publish profile will probably be the easiest route, but you should be able to override it if you're publishing some other way.